# Using SlimPHP in a hosting environment

Tags: android, slim

I am building a series of Android Apps that will be used by hotels to help with their operation. The backend for the apps to access the database is written using the SlimPHP microframework. Once I get the system is complete, my customers will be assigned a database for their information. I need a way of configuring Slim to use the assigned database name. The way I have it planned is when the customer signs up for an account with me, I will have a script that will create an account for the customer to include a database. The database with be identical from customer to customer. I just need a way to set SlimPHP to use the correct database. I was thinking of have the database name saved in android, and have that name sent to Slim from the app with each request. I am not sure how/if Slim can do it. Is it possible, or will I need to create my own API from PHP for my apps? If I need to provide more information, please let me know. Thanks for any help. Troy.

Comment: I wrote an article about this topic. This approach does not only work with PDO: [Slim 4 - Multitenancy](https://odan.github.io/2020/04/05/slim4-multiple-pdo-database-connections.html#multitenancy)

Comment: obviously, you need to create your own api. slim is a framework, using this you can create rest api's. and instead of restaurant name you should use some id kind of thing. Before that I would suggest you please go through some online documents to understand how to build a backed application with database and cache etc